# Unknown set of coordinates Northing Westing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, coordinates

I've been given a list of sites of vegetation with a "Northing/Westing" location e.g

```
52 43.569 - 001 44.833
```

I want to convert them to Easting Northing so I can load them into ArcMap. I've tried to convert the original coordinates but having a hard time determining the best way.

The best method so far is to convert them to Long/Lat

```
52.43569N / 1.44833W
```

in `gridreferencefinder`. However the location assigned to each record is different to the location found when using these new coordinates, off by about 20-30 miles.

Anyone know how to convert these locations to something more workable?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like normal WGS48 coordinates with grad and decimal minutes. The correct conversion in decimal coordinates would be:

```
Lat: 52° 43.569' (N) -> 52.72615
Lon: 1° 44.833' (E)  -> 1.747217
```

*Don't forget that minutes have max 60 counts so if you convert them into a decimal value divide it by 60. **Negative values are West***

Here is a easy example how to convert it with excel. Put each grad and minute value in one column:

[image: excel example]

The example formulas are:

```
E2 = A2+ROUND(B2/60/1000;6)
F2 = C2+ROUND(D2/60/1000;6)
```

I you are not sure you can always check a [online conversion tool](http://www.deine-berge.de/umrechner_koordinaten.php).

[image: online conversion example]

Hope that is correct and helping!

Comment: Sorry just found your minues between the coordinates. That stands for (W)... `N 52.72615 E -1.747217`

Comment: In that case the second formula should be `=C2-ROUND(D2/60/1000;6)`. Same for Southern latitudes.